# Ask for input, stops asking when enter is pressed, then displays an alphabetically sorted list, print each item separately on a diff line

Tags: python-3.x

**Challenge:**
Need to write a program that asks the user to enter some data, for instance the names of their friends. When the user wants to stop providing inputs, he just presses Enter. The program then displays ***an alphabetically sorted list*** of the data items entered. Do not just print the list, but print each item separately, on a different line.

```
y = []

def alfabetisch( element ):
    return element

while True:
    user_input = input("Prompt: ")
    if user_input != "":
        y += [user_input]
    if user_input == "":
        break

for element in y:
    y.sort( key= alfabetisch )
    print( element )
```

I've made some changes and it works 'sometimes' now. If I put in the following input at the 'prompt:' 
[Great, Amazing, Super, Sweet, Nice] it gives back: [Great, Great, Nice, Super, Sweet] so that is two times 'Great' and leaves out 'Amazing'

But when I give in the following input at the 'prompt:' [Amorf, Bread, Crest, Draft, Edith, Flood] it gives back: [Amorf, Bread, Crest, Draft, Edith, Flood], so with this particular input it does what I wanted it to do.

What am I doing wrong here, can anyone provide some pointers?

Comment: If the user doesn’t input anything, the result is the empty string `’’`, not `None`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Thnx, I tried that already. When I tested this I could only 'input data' once, then the program stopped.

Comment: Tried *what*, exactly? Without a loop, of course you only get one.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I've made some changes and it works 'sometimes' now. If I put in the following input at the 'prompt:' [Great, Amazing, Super, Sweet, Nice] it gives back: [Great, Great, Nice, Super, Sweet] so that is two times 'Great' and leaves out 'Amazing'.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: But when I give in the following input at the 'prompt:' [Amorf, Bread, Crest, Draft, Edith, Flood] it gives back: [Amorf, Bread, Crest, Draft, Edith, Flood], so with this particular input it does what I wanted it to do.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: see above for changes...

Comment: You sort the list *while you’re iterating over it*. Also the [mcve] should be **in the question**, not split between the Q and the comments.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: sorry for that, didn't realise this. Regarding your remark: 'You sort the list while you’re iterating over it.' I still don't completely understand, because I thought that the sorting happens only after I got out of the loop. Could you explain a bit more pls?

Comment: `for element in y: y.sort(...)` - how is that outside the loop?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Thank you very much for your mentorship! This really helped me a lot! (I've fixed it, see above for solution)

Comment: If you no longer have a question, *delete the question*.

Answer (score 0):

The input of a user is a string.
If the user doesn't input anything the output of `input()` function is `''` ( as mentioned in the comments).

If the user inputs more than one item, as you mentioned for instance a list of friend names then iterating over the string will give you all the chars that compose that string.

A more Pythonic way of doing that will be:

```
user_input = input("Prompt: ")
print('\n'.join(sorted(user_input.split())))
```